# How can I use fluidmovebehaviour for loading data in listbox

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

How can I use fluidmovebehaviour  for loading data in listbox. Any tips on how can I use this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% on this but I think the the ItemsPanelTemplate of your listbox needs to be set as a WrapPanel?

...or is your problem just setting the behavior?